# Common logic accessible from any twig template

Tags: templates, fosuserbundle, symfony

In SF3, I would like to know how to perform some logic that would be common to any page in my website.

[FOSUserBundle, global arguments / function before templating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388694/fosuserbundle-global-arguments-function-before-templating) is a begin of answer, but it talks about SF2, and i'm not sure if the OP is really expecting the same thing as me.

For the moment, I defined a custom base class (`BasePageController`) from which any controller inherits in my project.
The common logic is written there, and each controller calls a common method to retrieve
some custom variables to send to the twig templates.

Here is how it looks (I tried to make the smallest example as possible):

My base controller class:

```php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/BasePageController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BasePageController extends Controller
{
    public function getCommonParams()
    {
        // This assignement may be replaced by a complex logic,
        // evolving user-specific data, session variables... :
        $val = 1234;

        return [ 'important_val' => $val ];
    }
}
```

A controller example which inherits from my base class:

```php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/HomeController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Controller\BasePageController;

class HomeController extends BasePageController
{
    public function homeAction()
    {
        $params = $this->getCommonParams();
        return $this->render('home.html.twig', $params);
    }
}
```

A basic base template:

```html
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SO example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The template used by my controller example:

```html
{# app/Resources/views/home.html.twig #}

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>
    Important value : {{ important_val }}
</P>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not really sure if it's the common way to handle common logic in a SF website (advices are welcome about it).

But what is certain, is that problems start to appear when I try to use `FOSUserBundle` over this scheme.

Indeed, every controller inside the `FOSUserBundle` obviously doesn't inherit from my custom
controller class. So, even if redefine the FOSUserBundle templates, my common logic will
not be accessible from the login/register/... pages.

The only kinds of workarounds I can imagine now are:

- Include a whole controller with `{% render %}` (inherited from my custom class) inside the templates, where
  the common logic would be accessible; but the common logic would still be unavailable inside
  the main template (i.e. inside `login.html.twig`...);
- redefine all FOSUserBundle controllers by replacing their standard inheritance (`Controller`)
  by my own custom controller class; but i'm sure it's the worst idea of the year (I would
  loose all the flexibility offered by the composer upgrade system).

There might be a perfect solution if there was a magical twig tag that would import variables
from a PHP method, something like this:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}

{% import_my_variables_from('AppBundle:BasePageController:getCommonParams()') %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
....
```

So how is it possible to make some common logic accessible, even for external bundles like FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always a bit skeptical over the notion that you really need common parameters for every single page.  The requirement often goes away as the application design is refined.

But assuming you really need this then move the common parameter functionality to it's own service.

```
class CommonParameters {
    public function getParams() {
        return [whatever];
```

Wire it up as a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

```
services:
    common_parameters:
        class: AppBundle\Common\CommonParameters
```

From inside a controller, access the parameters with:

```
$params = $this->get('common_parameters')->getParams();
```

You could even define a trait to add this to your controllers and get rid of your custom base controller classes which happens to be another one of those ideas that sound really good but in practice often turn out to more painful that they are worth.

But what about twig?  This is where a twig extension can come in: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html.  You can inject your parameter service into your twig extension and twig will have access to these variables without involving controllers at all.  Plug in your own FOSUserBundle templates and off you go.

And of course, you can also inject this stuff into whatever other services might need it.  Think services.  Not globals.

Final note: Symfony is a secular framework.  Magical thinking won't get you very far.

Comment: Really helpful answer, tx; i'm sure you're right about the need (or not) of common parameters; but I really needed to answer clearly to this Q, to go deeper in my understanding of SF. I used the word 'magical' to help readers to see i'm a beginner, so they give me simple infos, like yours! tx again